# Среди двузначных чисел найти те, сумма квадратов цифр которых делится на 13 на ассемблере

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер

Практика по ассемблеру, сделал все задания кроме этого. Никак не понимаю, как это сделать.

Задача: Среди двузначных чисел найти те, сумма квадратов цифр которых делится на 13

Работаю в Visual Studio C++

Заранее всем спасибо)

Вот эта задача на C++, нужно перевести в ассемблерскую вставку

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int sumkvadr(int i)
{
    bool e;
    int q = i % 10;
    int w = i / 10;
    int sum = q * q + w * w;
    if (sum % 13 == 0)
        e = true;
    else
        e = false;
    return e;
}

void write(bool e, int& i)
{
    if (e == true)
        cout << i << " " << endl;
}

void main()
{
    for (int i = 10; i <= 99; i++) write(sumkvadr(i), i);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Так это должен быть чистый ассемблер, или ассемблерная вставка в код на С, например?

Comment: Покажите имеющийся код

Comment: @Mikhailo получается ассемблеровская вставка в С++, просто сейчас дистанционка, толком по ассемблеру нам ничего не объясняли. Спросить некого, препод единственный который есть по нему у нас - недоступен. Ни почты никто не знает, ни связи. Поэтому вот так(

Comment: @Mikhailo добавил код этой задачи на С++

Comment: Хороший способ изучения ассемблера это просмотр ассемблерного кода, который выдает компилятор. Пишете простенькую программу на Си и получаете ее код на ассемблере. В *nix обычно `gcc -S -Os t.c` создает файл `t.s`. Что-то подобное должно быть и в винде с visual-studio

Comment: Это мне не особо помогло.